# Set another xamlfile as mainwindow

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I created a custom window with a couple of elements like buttons, dropdown menues,...
Is it possible to use this window in other projects? I've already added the custom window's assembly to my current project. But I don't get it, how to open the custom window as mainwindow.

Answer (score 0):

The first window that gets creates in a WPF application becomes the main window. You can remove StartupUri from App.xaml and then create and show the window you want in App.xaml.cs in the OnStartup method (you'll need to override it).

Another option is to use pack URL in your app.xaml:

```
StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/ExternalAssemblyName;component/AnotherWindow.xaml"
```

or if the xaml file is in a subfolder:

```
StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/ExternalAssemblyName;component/YourFolderName/AnotherWindow.xaml"
```

You always need to specify component before the path to the xaml file. The assembly name shouldn't contain .dll part of the file name.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a possibility to edit the mainwindow in the app.xaml? There's an empty row in my mainwindow to put in something in the app.xaml. It doesnt work..

Comment: I've updated my answer and added one more way of doing it (through App.xaml)

Comment: thanks again. but it's still not possible to edit this inserted window. Am I only allowed to edit this window in its build class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You're not able to edit what file? Are you able to change App.xaml?

Comment: I open my custom window, lets call it WindowA (which is in an other assembly and has some forms inside) in app.xaml as mainwindow. Now I'm able to see the windowA. But is it possible to edit this windowA for example to create another button in the app.xaml.

Comment: Ok, so you want to reuse WindowA, but want to extend it in order to add more controls? In that case I'd recommend creating a UserControl in a separate assembly and reuse that instead of reusing a Window.

Comment: Right. My customwindow contains some forms inside, and also a new (selfmade) titlebar with a combobox. It also contains borders, to made the design of titlebar and borders unifotm. At first I had a UserControl. But with the borders it doesn't fit.. The possibility, in my opinion, is the customwindow..

Comment: You could subclass that custom window and then change it in your application, but that will cause too much trouble. There are a few blog posts about it and how XAML visualiser in visual studio can't handle it properly. Using UserControl would be a lot easier and tidier. You can always add borders in the application you are going to use that control